# PySpark-Py4JJavaError: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o58.showString

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

I currently set up spark and run a simple program that creat a job in spark node. However I keep receive this error.
My Spark version is 3.4.1, PySpark is 3.4.1, and Java is 1.8.0_202

I already config PYSPARK_PYTHON and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON direct to my python.exe
C://Python//Python310//python.exe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 899, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "C:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Spark\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 169, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o58.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (host.docker.internal executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

My program

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("GreetingExample").getOrCreate()

data = [("John", 28), ("Alice", 25), ("Bob", 32)]
columns = ["Name", "Age"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df.show()

spark.stop()
```